# Passing index to a function in powershell

Tags: powershell

In powershell inside a foreach I generate some buttons and every button should call a function passing its index as argument but it seems that you can't pass the index to the function.

```
$RacesButtons = @()
for( $i=0; $i -lt $numRaces; $i++ ){
    $button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $RacesButtons = $RacesButtons + $button
    $RacesButtons[$i].Text = "$($RacesFiles[$i])"
    $RacesButtons[$i].Add_Click({NewNpc $i})
    $Form.Controls.Add($RacesButtons[$i])
}
```

It should pass 0 to 8 ($numRaces is 9) but instead it pass null and I receive this error.

```
Indexing operation failed. The index value of the matrix is null.
 In C:\Users\Marco\Desktop\Music&Npc\Music&Npc.ps1:137 car:2
+     $NpcDetailsTextBox.Text = $RacesFiles[$race]
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArrayIndex
```

"NpcDetailsTextBox" is a textbox and "RacesFiles" is an array.
The strange thing is that the text of every button (setted with $RacesButtons[$i].Text = "$($RacesFiles[$i])" before setting the add_click) is correct.

I receive the same error with

```
$RacesButtons[$i].Add_Click({NewNpc $($i)})
```

But if I use one of these

```
$RacesButtons[$i].Add_Click({NewNpc "$i"})
$RacesButtons[$i].Add_Click({NewNpc "$($i)"})
```

it doesn't return an error but every button pass 0 to the function.

Any ideas on how can I solve this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is that inside the scriptblock for the `Add_Click`, the variable `$i` is unknown ($null).
In this case, I would go for an easy solution and use the buttons own `Tag` property to save the current value of `$i`

```
$RacesButtons = for( $i = 0; $i -lt $numRaces; $i++ ){
    $button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $button.Text = "$($RacesFiles[$i])"
    # store the value of $i in the button's Tag property so it will be kept
    $button.Tag  = $i
    $button.Add_Click({ NewNpc $this.Tag })
    $Form.Controls.Add($button)
    # output the new button so it gets collected in the $RacesButtons array
    $button
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: It works!
Thanks!
But I have a question on the second comment
You said that to add the button to the array I should output it with "$button" but I added to the array immediately after the creation with "$RacesButtons = $RacesButtons + $button", isn't it the same? (it works in the way I did, but maybe there's something wrong)

Comment: @MarcoF `$RacesButtons = $RacesButtons + $button` gives you the same result. The difference is that when adding items to an array like that, you are in fact recreating the entire array on each iteration, which is time and memory consuming. Of course, on a small array you wouldn't notice this, but tests show that collecting the array using `$RacesButtons = for(...)` is a lot faster.